# SUMPRODUCT of specific values only on weekends

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting, weekend

I have a workbook (say called W.xlsx) comprised of many sheets (say called S1, S2, S3 etc)  that contain days of the week, dates and text values in columns A, B and C respectively:

[image: example]

In another workbook (say called W2.xlsx) I am trying to use SUMPRODUCT in a cell to count how many times 4, 4SH, 18, 18J, and 00SH occur on Sat or Sun on S1 of W.xlsx.

I know it has to be something similar to this, but can't be this because the "2" in the formula won't work for single digits right??

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT([W.xlsx]S1!(WEEKDAY((B1:B15)>=6)*(C1:C15,2)="4","18","00"))))`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you confirm that column A contains actual dates formatted as *DDD*?

Comment: Column B has the actual dates in it, but the cells use the custom format "d".  Column A formats column B to the day of the week using =UPPER(TEXT(B1, "ddd"))

Answer (score 2):

The following should work regardless of whether you are working with real dates or text and whether or not you corrected the true numbers into text-that-looks-like-a-number.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(TEXT(A1:A15, "ddd;@"), 1)="S")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH(TEXT(C1:C15, "0;@"), {"4","4SH","18","18J","00SH"}, 0))), B1:B15)
```

[image]

Comment: maybe I didn't explain what I am trying to do well enough.  Your solution is adding up column B values that fall on Sat/Sun.  Column B are actually date fields with only "d" displayed in each cell.  So say B1 = 12/10/17, B2 = 12/11/17 etc.  What I want to do is count how many times 4, 4SH, 18, 18J, and 00SH occur on Sat or Sun on S1 of W.xlsx in a separate worksheet, W2.xlsx.  So the solution I am looking for is 1 for 4,18J and 00SH and 0 for the remainder.  Perhaps I need to use COUNTIF instead??

Comment: So remove `, B1:B15` for the count.